# Statistic of sales per day in the last 30 day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a quest that is about doing a statistic of the sales per day in the last 30 day...i've found a way to only show the last month:

```
SELECT * 
FROM purchase
WHERE date >= date('01-05-2021', current_date - interval '1 month')
  and date < date('01-05-2021', current_date)
```

the columns in purchase are just id, value, date, cashier and store id what do you think is the best way to do this?
i have this and i don't know way it is not working...i'm new in postgresql so please don't be offended by this

Answer (score 0):

Group by `date` and use `sum` to find the total.

```
select date,sum(value)
from purchase
where date between current_date - interval '1 month' and current_date - 1
group by date
```